Yes, I need to convert a 400-page Word thesis to LaTeX. Any easy method available?
I am a final year graduate student and I have my thesis (about 400 pages) in Microsoft Word format. I would like to convert the document into a LaTeX "camera" ready PDF. Is there any easy way to do this? I am very new to LateX

pandoc is probably your best bet -- however be aware that the result won't be perfect and will need some fixing.

The success of whatever conversion program you end up selecting will depend greatly on how disciplined you've been, in terms of using Word's capabilities for applying structure to the document, when you created the Word-format file. If you've mainly relied on visual formatting, any conversion program will likely struggle to create good-looking output.

Welcome! To the best of my knowledge, the honest answer to this question is 'No'. But there are tools which can make it easier.

All are correct. Pandoc will play ok as long as your docx is properly formatted. Iirc Pandoc doesn't write the config file for you so might want to construct the config first and input contents later. Split your document into different files to avoid headaches. Of course, sadly having some know-how knowledge of using LaTeX will immensely help to carry all these process.

I don't understand your needs. If your goal is to produce a camera ready PDF, why not just export as PDF from Word? Why go through the extra work sending it into LaTeX?

as @WillieWong says, your request sounds rather strange. Using latex would have been a good choice at the start fo writing your thesis, but converting to an editable source form at the end of the process sounds strange, what do you intend to do with the latex version of the document going forward? It will be quite a lot of work to convert the Word document to a maintainable latex source, and if all you plan to do is print it once to hand in the thesis this seems a wasted effort if you could just hand in the document you have.

There are already several questions like yours, e.g., Converting MS Word .doc to LaTeX by command line, How can I import an exam or assignment from Word into LaTeX?, How can I convert from Microsoft Word to a LaTeX document. An alternative to the conversion is discussed in: Make MS Word document look like it has been typeset in LaTeX. BTW: I've changed the tags to make finding related questions easier.
